# Error con tilde y ñ en un Script de php

Tags: javascript, php, json

tengo un problema con un Script de PHP cuando cuando tengo datos en la base que contengan "ñ" o Tildes, estoy usando este Script pero no se en que punto hacer la conversión a UTF-8.

```
 <?php 
 //Importing Database Script 
 require_once('Connectdb.php');

 //Creating sql query
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM bebidas ";

 //getting result 
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 //creating a blank array 
 $result = array();

 //looping through all the records fetched
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($r)){

 //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
 array_push($result,array(

 "bid"=>$row['bid'],
 "nombre"=>$row['nombre'],
 "precio"=>$row['precio'],

 ));
 }

 //Displaying the array in json format 
 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Devuelve NULL al tener estos caracteres, agradezco su respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

justo despues de la conexion a la base de datos puedes agregar esto...

```
       $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

el mas recomendado es este...

```
       $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

quedaría algo parecido a esto....

```
       $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost, usuario, clave, basedatos);
       $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Espero te sirva, saludos...

Comment: Me sirvió a la perfección muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si tus scripts PHP acceden a una base de datos MySQL, es posible que la información se esté guardando con una codificación diferente a UTF-8, incluso aunque hayas utilizado todas las precauciones explicadas en la sección anterior.

Para asegurarte de que la información que viaja entre PHP y MySQL se mantenga codificada con UTF-8, comprueba que las bases de datos y todas sus tablas tienen el valor utf8mb4 tanto en la opción character set como en la opción collation. Asegúrate también de que la conexión PDO utiliza el valor utf8mb4 en la opción character set. Todo esto es extremadamente importante.

Si utilizas como valor utf8, no obtendrás soporte UTF-8 completo. El único valor que lo garantiza es utf8mb4.

Utiliza la función mb_http_output() para asegurarte que el contenido generado por tu script PHP está codificado con UTF-8.

Después es necesario decirle al navegador que los contenidos de la página deben procesarse como UTF-8. Para ello, tradicionalmente se utilizaba la etiqueta charset dentro del elemento  de la página. Aunque esta opción todavía funciona, ahora se recomienda indicar la codificación mediante la cabecera Content-Type de HTTP ya que es mucho más rápido.

```
<?php
// Esto le dice a PHP que usaremos cadenas UTF-8 hasta el final
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

// Esto le dice a PHP que generaremos cadenas UTF-8
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, muy bien explicada, entendí todo lo que explicaste. Pero para mi caso la respuesta de @Alberto fue la indicada. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay problema..